# inline-block boxes not fitting in their container

Tags: html, css, border-box

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, I thought that by adding border-box, it would fit those 4 boxes neatly.

http://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/x3ftdx6n/

```css
.ok{
width:300px;
    background:red;
    height:100px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.box{
    display:inline-block; 
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:25%;
    border:2px solid blue;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="ok">
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
<div class="box">4</div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that `inline-block` elements are, by default, rendered with a bit of extra space.

Why? Because a `div` set to `inline-block` has some inline element characteristics.

A space or line break between `span` elements will result in a space rendered by the browser.

Similarly, if you're writing text in a `<p>` element, every time you hit the space bar or add a line break a space will be rendered by the browser.

This same rule applies to `inline-block` divs. A space or line break in the source will result in a space rendered. This creates unexpected width, which can result in an overflow or wrapping.

One solution is to remove all whitespace between elements in the source:

```css
.ok {
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 25%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="ok"><div class="box">1</div><div class="box">2</div><div class="box">3</div><div class="box">4</div></div>
```

Another method sets `font-size: 0` on the parent and, if necessary, restores the font on the child:

```css
.ok {
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 0;
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 25%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ok">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
</div>
```

Other options include *negative margins*, *omitting closing tags*, *using comment tags*, *floats* and *flexbox*. See this article for more details:

- [Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Comment: Beautiful explanation and links are super helpful, I love you, marry?

Answer (score 1):

I would insist you to **add just one property.** One which removes spaces between`box` div. Just add `float:left;` to your `.box` class/div.

[Demo : UPDATED](http://jsfiddle.net/x3ftdx6n/9/)

```css
.ok{
    margin:0px auto; /* ADDED */
    width:300px;
    background:red;
    height:100px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:0px auto;
}

.box{
    display:inline-block; 
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:25%;
    border:2px solid blue;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="ok">
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
<div class="box">4</div>
    
</div>
```

**UPDATE :** To center it add **just one more** property `margin:0px auto;` to your `.ok` class/div. CHECK OUT THE UPDATED DEMO AND SNIPPET.

> **Note :** This would make your text in `box` div left aligned, so if you want it center just add `text-align:center;` to your `.box` class in CSS.

Comment: Works awesome, only problem is if I want it to be centered, it doesn't work out.  But pointed me in the right direction.