# align div elements in div container using flexbox

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox

can you help me here in this issue? I have this div which contains 7 divs. Currently, using the flex box, I get this output

[image]

However, what I want to happen should be like this:

[image]

Below are some codes that I roughly have

```css
.Container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}
.Items {
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 10px;
  border: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="Items">
    <img height="40px" width="40px" src="http://img10.deviantart.net/af75/i/2014/242/1/9/kawaii_potato_by_hashtagpony-d7xbs1t.png" />
    <br/>
    <span>Icon 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="Items">
    <img height="40px" width="40px" src="http://img10.deviantart.net/af75/i/2014/242/1/9/kawaii_potato_by_hashtagpony-d7xbs1t.png" />
    <br/>
    <span>Icon 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="Items">
    <img height="40px" width="40px" src="http://img10.deviantart.net/af75/i/2014/242/1/9/kawaii_potato_by_hashtagpony-d7xbs1t.png" />
    <br/>
    <span>Icon 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="Items">
    <img height="40px" width="40px" src="http://img10.deviantart.net/af75/i/2014/242/1/9/kawaii_potato_by_hashtagpony-d7xbs1t.png" />
    <br/>
    <span>Icon 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="Items">
    <img height="40px" width="40px" src="http://img10.deviantart.net/af75/i/2014/242/1/9/kawaii_potato_by_hashtagpony-d7xbs1t.png" />
    <br/>
    <span>Icon 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="Items">
    <img height="40px" width="40px" src="http://img10.deviantart.net/af75/i/2014/242/1/9/kawaii_potato_by_hashtagpony-d7xbs1t.png" />
    <br/>
    <span>Icon 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="Items">
    <img height="40px" width="40px" src="http://img10.deviantart.net/af75/i/2014/242/1/9/kawaii_potato_by_hashtagpony-d7xbs1t.png" />
    <br/>
    <span>Icon 1</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**
Thank you for those who replied. However, I forgot to add these things.

1. I want that the icons be spread out evenly that's why I need the `justify-content: space-around`
2. I also want that the icons be horizontally at the center that's why I used the `align-items: center; align-content: center;`

The problem is this: Is it possible to have both?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `justify-content: space-around` use `justify-content: flex-start`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rsvmsku6/

---

**Update** (based on comments):

For guidance creating a grid that is horizontally centered, but the child elements are left-aligned, see these posts:

- [How to center a flex container but left-align flex items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32802202/3597276)
- [Center align container and left align child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33192745/3597276)

Comment: You want the icons aligned-left with space in between (like in your second image), but you want the container centered horizontally on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following css from Container:

```
justify-content: space-around;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
justify-content: space-around;
```

That's your problem. If you remove that line, the items will display as you want them too

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/65Luuys8/1/)

`space-around`:

> items are evenly distributed in the line with equal space around them

`flex-start` (default)

> items are packed toward the start line

Comment: Don't know why this got a downvote so I'll balance you out

Answer (score 0):

You dont have a need for some of the elements.

- `align-items`
- `align-content`

and you also need to set the `justify-content` to be `flex-start` which will always set it to the left.

```css
.Container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 320px;
}
.Items {
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 10px;
  border: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="Items">
    <img height="40px" width="40px" src="http://img10.deviantart.net/af75/i/2014/242/1/9/kawaii_potato_by_hashtagpony-d7xbs1t.png" />
    <br/>
    <span>Icon 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="Items">
    <img height="40px" width="40px" src="http://img10.deviantart.net/af75/i/2014/242/1/9/kawaii_potato_by_hashtagpony-d7xbs1t.png" />
    <br/>
    <span>Icon 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="Items">
    <img height="40px" width="40px" src="http://img10.deviantart.net/af75/i/2014/242/1/9/kawaii_potato_by_hashtagpony-d7xbs1t.png" />
    <br/>
    <span>Icon 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="Items">
    <img height="40px" width="40px" src="http://img10.deviantart.net/af75/i/2014/242/1/9/kawaii_potato_by_hashtagpony-d7xbs1t.png" />
    <br/>
    <span>Icon 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="Items">
    <img height="40px" width="40px" src="http://img10.deviantart.net/af75/i/2014/242/1/9/kawaii_potato_by_hashtagpony-d7xbs1t.png" />
    <br/>
    <span>Icon 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="Items">
    <img height="40px" width="40px" src="http://img10.deviantart.net/af75/i/2014/242/1/9/kawaii_potato_by_hashtagpony-d7xbs1t.png" />
    <br/>
    <span>Icon 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="Items">
    <img height="40px" width="40px" src="http://img10.deviantart.net/af75/i/2014/242/1/9/kawaii_potato_by_hashtagpony-d7xbs1t.png" />
    <br/>
    <span>Icon 1</span>
  </div>
</div>
```