# How to align the items to the start and center the flex container?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have <s>[this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gZHmQJa4OlEJTksjLHYm?p=preview)</s> [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JFRNh5IW67Khh7meBtvm?p=preview).

I'm trying to horizontal align the flex container while maintaining their items aligned to the start.

<s>I'm trying to `align-content: flex-start` while using the `justify-content: center`.</s>

Right now, if the last row has less items it will be centered to the flex container instead of the start of the row.

### Update 1

Here is the expected result:

[image]

Comment: justify-content is for horizontal alignment, align-items for vertical alignment.

Comment: By default, `justify-content` is horizontal and `align-items` is vertical, but the `flex-direction` property can change that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) and [`align-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-content) properties can be applied only to the *flex container*, but impact only *flex items*. So to center the container you would have to apply `justify-content: center` to the parent of `.flex-container` (`body`, in this case).

Alternatively, you could simply use [`auto` margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins) on `.flex-container`.

The `align-content` property works along the cross-axis of the flex container (the vertical plane, in this case) and isn't necessary to fix your layout.

Try this:

```
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-container {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-start;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

[**modified plunker demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/qKvvNgeTTg6a63TO5BTE?p=preview)

OR THIS:

```
.flex-container {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-start;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[**modified plunker demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/L1at3IlBP49vQoSO5Xg1?p=preview)

**UPDATE** (based on comments)

To address the issue of extra whitespace along the right side of the container, see here:

- [How to center a flex container but left-align flex items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32802202/center-flex-container-but-align-left-flex-items)
- [Center align container and left align child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33192745/3597276)
- [Left aligned last row in centered grid of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19527104/3597276)

Comment: the flex container is centered but the content is not always completely in the center. The right part will have more space compared to the left one.

Comment: Yes, that's a known issue. Your original question didn't mention that requirement, which is why I didn't go in that direction. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32811002/3597276

Comment: Don't you need to know the width of the 'flex-container' too?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution with `grid`:

It's a bit complex, but it works, if you nest two grids like this:

```css
.grid {
    overflow: hidden;

    --grid__col-width: 200px;
    --grid__column-gap: 20px;
    --grid__row-gap: 20px;
  
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.grid__outer-grid {
    display: grid;
    margin: 0 calc(var(--grid__column-gap) * -1);
    
    column-gap: var(--grid__column-gap);
    row-gap: var(--grid__row-gap);
    
    --grid__column-gap-double: calc(var(--grid__column-gap) * 2);
    --grid__column-gap-half: calc(var(--grid__column-gap) / 2);
    --grid__row-gap-half: calc(var(--grid__row-gap) / 2);
    --grid__inner-grid: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min(var(--grid__col-width), calc(100% - var(--grid__column-gap-double))), var(--grid__col-width)));
    grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr) [grid-start] var(--grid__inner-grid) [grid-end] minmax(0, 1fr);
}

.grid__inner-grid {
    display: grid;
    
    grid-column-start: grid-start;
    grid-column-end: grid-end;
    
    column-gap: var(--grid__column-gap);
    row-gap: var(--grid__row-gap);
    
    grid-template-columns: var(--grid__inner-grid);
}

.box {
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid__outer-grid">
        <div class="grid__inner-grid">
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/xaver_cookis/pen/wvPeBLe)

Comment: Found a much simpler solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19527104/left-aligned-last-row-in-centered-grid-of-elements):

https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/QpBxmr?editors=1100

It's possible to use `justify-content: center` with a grid.