# Center group of items horizontally, but left align items

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

I think it's easier to explain it visually. Here is the code I have.

```
<Box
    sx={{
        height: 500,
        paddingTop: 5,
    }}
>
<Box
    sx={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "flex-start",
        flexWrap: "wrap",
    }}
>
    {items}
</Box>
</Box>;
```

Produces this result:
[image: Bad result]

This is what I want it to look like. The group of items are centered on the page, but they are still left aligned.
[image: Good result]

If I simply change the justifyContent to "center" on the inner Box it will not achieve what I am going for. If I do justifyContent "center" on the outer it does nothing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to align the items to the start and center the flex container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33551865/how-to-align-the-items-to-the-start-and-center-the-flex-container)

Comment: Was not able to get it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32802202/3597276