# How to remove extra space on right side of an inline childs container?

Tags: html, css

I have a parent container that contain some inline child elements and the parent container has dynamic width. It looks great till all child elements are in one line but when you shrink the browser window and a child element go to the next line then it leave extra space on right side in parent container. As you can see the extra space between child and container's border in below image.

[image]

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #F00;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

I wanna know two things:

1: Why don't the parent container's width shrink after an inline child element go to the next line?

2: Is there any workaround to remove that extra space with CSS?

---

<sub>Please note that I used the `display: inline-block;` for `.child` tags just to demonstrate that but I can also use any css property like `flex` or `float` to achieve that.</sub>

Comment: Remaining space is not enough for the element to fit..

Comment: Not same, but similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33192745/center-align-container-and-left-align-child-elements)  and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19527104/left-aligned-last-row-in-centered-grid-of-elements), short answer is using @media.

Comment: what about a flexbox?

Comment: I just want my container width equal to my child divs width even after a child go to next line. I can use flexbox solution or any workaround to achieve it.

Comment: @Pangloss I can't use `@media` queries coz there could be more or less child divs

Comment: OK, one more thing isn't very clear - so are you also open to flex or float solution? or you know it already.

Comment: yeah sure and I've already tried flex and other solutions but they didn't work for me and I set the childs width 100px for demo but some child elements contain images and other stuff too so it's not possible to give them percentage width.

Comment: You can do something like this with Flexbox https://jsfiddle.net/stqcckys/2/

Comment: @NenadVracar The width of child elements aren't same and some can have fixed width too also I'm not looking for a solution to keep all child divs in one line.

Comment: In CSS, when a child item wraps, the parent container *does not* recalculate its width to shrink-wrap the fewer columns. See my answer here for more details and a possible workaround (using pure CSS and `inline-block`). http://stackoverflow.com/a/32811002/3597276

Comment: There is no simple solution to this...it's the way line boxes work...it's a common request.

Comment: Adding to my comment above, the gap on the right represents the space that was occupied by the item before it wrapped. The container doesn't care; it stays on its original course regardless.

Comment: @Michael_B Thanks your comment is really helpful to understand that but like I said in above comment I can't media queries.

Comment: In CSS, the only solutions to this problem that I have experience with are: (1) knowing the fixed-width of the container, and the fixed-size of the items, or (2) using media queries. There may be other methods, but I don't think they'll be simpler. However, this should be a pretty easy fix with JS.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) instead. Change the display of the parent container to `display: flex` and a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amberjasmijn/qxsb5fo9/1/).

After reading the post again, I'm not sure if you especially want to use `display: inline-block`. Sorry bout that!

Comment: How does this solve the problem? You simply disabled the wrapping.

Comment: If you restore the wrapping, the problem still exists: https://jsfiddle.net/qxsb5fo9/3/

Comment: Yeah, I see. Didn't read properly before posting, sorry! It's an interesting question though, still trying some things :) isn't there a solution with Sass?

Comment: You're welcome to revise your answer with any solutions you may have. Just note the requirements in the question. I'm not sure Sass is an acceptable option.