# How can I set a left align for the last element which is into a center container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```css
.container{
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}

.box{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">sth</div>
  <div class="box">sth</div>
  <div class="box">sth</div>
  <div class="box">sth</div>
  <div class="box">sth</div>
</div>
```

As you see, the last element is also center. While I need to keep in the same line *(vertically)* on left column. So this is the expected result:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32802202/how-to-center-a-flex-container-but-left-align-flex-items

Comment: and - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33192745/center-align-container-and-left-align-child-elements?rq=1

Comment: Are you willing to change your markup?

Comment: @Mr.Alien I can change everything .. Both HTML and CSS codes. I just need to keep boxes in the container center, and set the last box in the same line of left column (vertically).

Comment: @MartinAJ say I am resizing the screen and there are two boxes in the second row and three in the first, do you want to bottom two boxes to be centered?

Comment: @Mr.Alien no, two boxes should be in the left side, exactly in the same line of columns.

Comment: @MartinAJ refer to comment 1 of Paulie, follow the flex box approach

Comment: @Mr.Alien Apparently I have to `:-(` .. You know, I  **hate** `@media`.

Comment: @MartinAJ Yea cuz apparently it seems to be a simplistic approach if used flex box ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use `float:left` on your block.

You need to add nested div and set a width on it.

Then your `box` elements will all be centered to the nested div and have your last box in the left column.

```css
.center {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left:auto%;
    margin-right:auto%;
    width: 100%;  
}
.container{
    margin-left:25%;
    margin-right:25%; 
    width:40%;
    border: 1px solid;  

}

.box{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px;

}
```

```html
<div class="center">
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">sth</div>
  <div class="box">sth</div>
  <div class="box">sth</div>
  <div class="box">sth</div>
  <div class="box">sth</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want a fix width *(`px`)* as the container's width.

Comment: I changed it to a pct. But that pct needs to be set based on the relative widths of your inner box.

Comment: If you take a look at boot strap, that is why they have col-md-2 to col-md-12.

Comment: The containing box now needs `overflow:auto` in order to automatically stretch vertically.

Answer (score 1):

Try with floating property .And fix the container with min heigh

```css
.container{
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  min-height:150px;
}

.box{
  float:left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">sth</div>
  <div class="box">sth</div>
  <div class="box">sth</div>
  <div class="box">sth</div>
  <div class="box">sth</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems my question isn't clear enough. Because in your code, all boxes are in the left side of container. while I need to keep in the container center.

Answer (score 1):

I added some background colours for you to see what the containers are doing.

```css
.container{
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: silver;
  
}

.box{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.innerContainer {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin: auto;
}

.row {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" align="center">
  <div class="innerContainer">
    <div class="box">sth</div>
    <div class="box">sth</div>
    <div class="box">sth</div>
    <div class="box">sth</div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="box">sth</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Center is not valid html5

Comment: I don't want a fix width *(`px`)* as the container's width.

Comment: I wasn't able to do it without a set number of px. Sorry. I tried :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this I think it will work fine if you want it to be responsive I will help you with `mediaQuery`.

```css
.container {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: colomn;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: stretch;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">sth</div>
  <div class="box">sth</div>
  <div class="box">sth</div>
  <div class="box">sth</div>
  <div class="box">sth</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well you know, I want a fixed width for boxes.

Comment: @MartinAJ Do you want it to responsible also?

Comment: Yes, that's actually the question `:-)`

Comment: @MartinAJ i have changed my code can you please check it

Comment: Now boxes aren't center.

Comment: @MartinAJ, I have changed my code but it will be not be centred. if you want it to the center we have to put a wrap inside `.container` and then centre the content inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Use **`float:left;`** inside box class, like:

```
.box{
   display: inline-block;
   border: 1px solid red;
   width: 100px;
   height: 20px;
   margin: 10px;
   float: left;
}
```