# display: inline-block not working. How do I make it work?

Tags: html, css

I've searched for other solutions here in stackoverflow but found no luck unfortunately. If there is an answer that already exist to my question then I apologize, and please link the answer to me :)

Anyway I have to divs but display: inline-block; is not working. I want them to be right next to each other WITHOUT using float. How do I achieve this? I must be missing something here..

here's the jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/frxme8z8/

Thanks in advance folks!

```
.context {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #72ED80;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px
}
```

Comment: You have the width at 50% _and_ 10px padding. You need to reduce the width.

Comment: Maybe replace `display: inline-block` with `float: left;`

Comment: @Thaillie, he mentioned in the question that he doesn't want to use `float`.

Comment: It worked! I used width: calc(50% - 10px);

Comment: But then i thought padding:10px wouldnt affect anything since I set the divs to box-sizing:border-box;. What went wrong?

Comment: @JB_, I didn't read that part :p

Comment: @Thaillie, It happens ;)

Comment: @billybobjones, maybe this can help [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32801275/4050842)

Answer (score 2):

just set your `.context` width to 49 %

```css
.context {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 49%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #72ED80;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 800px
}
```

```html
<div class="context"></div>
<div class="context"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @imGaurav is correct. Because you've set the size to 50% there is nomore space for the gap between ;)

So just set the width to 49% and everything will work :)

```
.context {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 49%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #72ED80;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 800px
}
```

Otherwise you can change you're padding to 0px but then, you don't have a gap between it anymore ;)

Answer (score 0):

your problem is the whitespaces. I see u did it `with 50% - 10px`...the correct way is `50% - 8px` actually...OR if u want a cleaner version, just remove the whitespace in your html file like in this fiddle i made https://jsfiddle.net/r9LrLva1/