# CSS Issue, space between elements makes no sense

Tags: html, css

I have got a weird space in two elements on [this page](http://karl.uphero.com/admin.php) and it doesn't make any sense! There should be no white gap between the border on the `ul` on the left, and the `div` on the right. The blue sections should touch, load the page and it will make sense.

This is the HTML for that part:

```
<div class="messages">
    <ul class="messageList">
        <li style="background-color:#2e89e6;color:#FFF;">
            <div>Martyn Ball</div>
            <p>This is a brief mess...</p>
            <span>07/12/2015</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>Martyn Ball</div>
            <p>This is a brief mess...</p>
            <span>07/12/2015</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>Martyn Ball</div>
            <p>This is a brief mess...</p>
            <span>07/12/2015</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="messageContent">
        <div class="messageContentTitle">
            <span class="name">Martyn Ball</span>
            <span class="date">07/12/2015 02:24PM</span>
        </div>
        This is a brief message, more will be loaded here!
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
/* Messages Styles */
.messageList {
    list-style:none;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0; padding:0;
    display:inline-block;
    border:solid #2e89e6;
    border-width:0px 5px 0px 0px;
    width:20%;
}
.messageList li p {
    font-size:14px;
    margin:0px;
}
.messageList li div {
    font-weight:bold;
}
.messageList li span {
    font-size:12px;
}
.messageList li {
    border:solid #e5e5e5;
    border-width:0px 0px 1px 1px;
    padding:8px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.messageList li:hover {
    background-color:#2e89e6;
    color:#FFF;
}
.messageContent {
    vertical-align:top;
    overflow: hidden;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:left;
    width:75%;
}
.messageContentTitle {
    color:#FFF;
    background-color:#2e89e6;
    margin:0;
    padding:5px;
    width:100%;
}
.messageContentTitle name { float:left; }
.messageContentTitle date { float:right; }
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Those two elements are `inline-block`. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32801275/3597276

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because both the `div` and `ul` are `inline-block` elements, which means that they display the whitespace in between.

This is my favorite solution to such an issue. Set the `font-size` of the parent to 0, and then set the `font-size` of the inline-block elements to the size that you need [I set it using `rem`s, but you can use whichever unit you need in your project].

```
.messages {
  font-size: 0;
}

.messageList, .messageContent {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

The other options are to comment out the whitespace between the elements.

```
<div class="messages">
    <ul class="messageList">
        ...
    </ul><!--
    --><div class="messageContent">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Or, to remove all the whitespace, altogether.

```
<div class="messages">
    <ul class="messageList">
        ...
    </ul><div class="messageContent">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I prefer the first solution over the others, as it keeps the HTML more readable.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the issue!