# List elements are being displayed out of order

Tags: javascript, html, css

... when inserted dynamically.  I would not have intuited this, and find it hard to believe this is expected behavior, but when I dynamically insert list elements by changing their display with JavaScript, they display out of order.  This pic sums it up.

Is this expected or a bug?

[image]

Code that matches the display type:

```
    Backbone.on('user_sign_in', function () {
        $A.log('user_sign_in event')
        if (getComputedStyle(self.E.main_nav, null).display === 'block') {
            self.E.user_menu.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            self.E.user_menu.style.display = "inline-block";
        }
    });
```

One solution causes this issue:

[image]

Comment: there is a `span` in between `li` and span is `inline` element

Comment: Do you apply some css to span with id user_menu? Because that entire span is displaced, I guess it's due to some css it inherits or applied to .

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.

Comment: `<ul>` elements can't have anything other than `<li>` elements as children.

Comment: No, only the child `<li>` can then contain more `<ul>`  and `<ol>` elements, but as far as children go, only `<li>` are valid as childen of both `<ul>` and `<ol>` elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may have something to do with putting a `span` inside a `ul`, which is invalid HTML.

> [**`<ul>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul)
>
> *Permitted content:*
>
> zero or more `<li>` elements, eventually mixed with `<ol>` and `<ul>` elements.

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul

---

If you need to create sub-groups of list items, then nest your lists.

```
<ul>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

---

**Update** (based on comments and revised question)

In your nav screenshot, the gap along the bottom margin may be caused by `display: inline-block`.

Here are two methods for removing it:

- change the `display` value to `block`
- add `vertical-align: bottom` to the rule

For an explanation and other methods see this post:

- [inline-block boxes not fitting in their container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32801095/3597276)

Comment: Sure, I added in your code and also posted a pic in the question.

Comment: On this line: `<ul id="user_menu" style="display: inline-block">`, try switching the `display` value to `block`.

Comment: If you don't want to change the `display` value, then add `vertical-align: bottom;` to the inline style.

Comment: each fixed issue seems to create a new issue, so I scrapped the idea of grouping these elements and just toggle them separately.

Comment: Well, good effort. It worked in Chrome Dev Tools. But obviously you need a more comprehensive solution. Good luck.

Comment: yep, my fingers are numb, thanks for the help. on to the next problem.

Answer (score 0):

there are two different menu classes in there: `.user-menu` (in the span tag) and `.top-menu` (including all items, also the span). Probably they have different CSS... Also the use of that span is a bit strange...

Comment: They have the same display, I match it explicitly in JavaScript.

Comment: what do you mean by "display"?

Comment: the css property `display:none`