# how to set a font size and padding percentage to be equal each boxes?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I did some research with font size and boxes sizes. I created ul li and styling them with some CSS to make them looks like a table and stay inline. after the epic code i realize that each words are different like home, tutorial, contact us, and registration. all font have a different sizes and different paddings to use.

so this is my code...
i tidy this up so it's not looks like in my localhost. what i did was made the percentage like 3.5754% to set the padding to get the exact SAME width of the boxes. so 4 of them should be the same size of boxes.

at home i created padding like 5% or so.
at tutorial i created padding like 3.something%
and etc.

because each words has a different width and number of letters.

sorry for my English, please let me know if i'm confusing u guys..
but please help about this percentage and font thing. i really don't get it. if u guys have some article to read it's also help... because i'm still looking for it. ty guys :)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.navigation {
  top: 0;
  width: 90%;
  height: 120px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav-head {
  padding-top: 5%;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin:
  /*0 7.2%*/
  ;
}
.nav a {
  color: #e74c3c;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.nav {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  border: solid 1px #e74c3c;
  margin-left: 0;
}
#nav1 {
  padding: 1% 1%;
}
#nav2 {
  padding: 1% 5.74%;
}
#nav3 {
  padding: 1% 3%;
}
#nav4 {
  padding: 1% 3%;
}
.nav:hover {
  padding: 2.2% 5%;
  border: solid 1px #e74c3c;
}
.nav.currentpage {
  padding: 2.2% 5%;
  border: solid 1px #e74c3c;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul class="nav-head">
    <li class="nav" id="nav1"><a href="#">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav" id="nav2"><a href="#">REGISTRATION</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav" id="nav3"><a href="#">TUTORIAL</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav" id="nav4"><a href="#">CONTACT US</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: So do you want all four boxes to have width of the largest box?

Comment: Why you use .currentpage in css and where is currentpage class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using percentages is not always the best idea, specially for padding. Instead, use min-width, a normal padding and control the gutter with font-size:0 on the parent and normal padding on the LIs

Here is the code:

```
.nav-head{
  font-size:0;
}
.nav {
  padding: 2px 5px !important;
  min-width: 116px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 !important;
  font-size: 15px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

And here is the [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGEWWe)

Here is the explanation on the font-zero concept [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801095/why-dont-these-4-inline-block-boxes-fit-neatly-in-their-container/32801275#32801275)

Comment: sorry, its too long for trying the answer from 1 and another. and wow man, i guess u got the best answer.

u r very clever, its not about the font-size i think. it's about the min-width and the padding u gave to the boxes.. am i right?

Comment: @newguy Along those lines, but the font-size will clear the margin between the nav items so that they are stuck together. Unless you actually do want the gap between them, then you don't need that. But yes, the min-width and padding is how you control the real estate :) If you like the answer, mark it as such and others will benefit from it (y)

Comment: nice man... i get it now.. tyvm... ok now i can play game because of u. lol

Answer (score 2):

2 easy option I believe:

1) `display:table` + `table-layout:fixed;`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.navigation {
  width: 90%;
  height: 120px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav-head {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  padding:0;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
.nav a {
  color: #e74c3c;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.nav {
  display:table-cell;
  border: solid 1px #e74c3c;
}
#nav1 {
}
#nav2 {
}
#nav3 {
}
#nav4 {
}
.nav:hover {
  border: solid 1px ;
}
.nav.currentpage {
  border: solid 1px ;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul class="nav-head">
    <li class="nav" id="nav1"><a href="#">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav" id="nav2"><a href="#">REGISTRATION</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav" id="nav3"><a href="#">TUTORIAL</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav" id="nav4"><a href="#">CONTACT US</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

2) `display:flex` + `flex:1;`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.navigation {
  width: 90%;
  height: 120px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav-head {
  display:flex;
  padding:0;
  list-style-type:none;
}
.nav a {
  color: #e74c3c;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.nav {
  flex:1;
  border: solid 1px #e74c3c;
}
#nav1 {
}
#nav2 {
}
#nav3 {
}
#nav4 {
}
.nav:hover {
  border: solid 1px ;
}
.nav.currentpage {
  border: solid 1px ;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul class="nav-head">
    <li class="nav" id="nav1"><a href="#">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav" id="nav2"><a href="#">REGISTRATION</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav" id="nav3"><a href="#">TUTORIAL</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav" id="nav4"><a href="#">CONTACT US</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flexbox to help you in making all the items with same width.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.navigation {
  top: 0;
  width: 90%;
  height: 120px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav-head {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 5%;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav a {
  color: #e74c3c;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.nav {
  list-style: none;
  flex: 1;
  border: solid 1px #e74c3c;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-top: 2.2%;
  padding-bottom: 2.2%;
}
.nav:hover {
  border: solid 1px #e74c3c;
}
.nav.currentpage {
  padding-top: 2.2%;
  padding-bottom: 2.2%;
  border: solid 1px #e74c3c;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul class="nav-head">
    <li class="nav" id="nav1"><a href="#">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav" id="nav2"><a href="#">REGISTRATION</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav" id="nav3"><a href="#">TUTORIAL</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav" id="nav4"><a href="#">CONTACT US</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```