# How do I keep a button appended to an input even at a smaller page width?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to append a button to a text input.

It works when I am in desktop mode, but when you change the size to a mobile-viewing size the button separates from the input.

Here [is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hjpa4bf6/).

I am using purecss:

```css
input {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  height: 30px;
}
.pure-button {
  margin-left: -45px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  padding: 1px;
}
span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  align-self: flex-start;
  background: red;
  background-position: 0 0;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="pure-g">
  <div class="pure-u-1">
    <form class="pure-form">
      <fieldset>
        <input type="text" class="pure-input-1-2" />
        <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">
          <span></span>
        </button>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd suggest re-thinking your design strategy. If you type a long word, it will go behind the button. Place the button next to the input, not over it.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović I put "padding-right: 50px" for the input button...even with that it will break?

Answer (score 0):

The library you're using is adding `display: block` to the `input` in a media query. That's forcing the button to the next line.

[image]

Add this to your CSS:

```
input, button { 
    display: inline-block !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

The `!important` is needed to override the PURECSS code. Otherwise, alter the code in the source.

I also removed all whitespace between the elements in the code:

```
<input type="text" class="pure-input-1-2" /><button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary"><span></span></button>
```

This is one method for [removing spaces between inline-block elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32801275/3597276).

[revised fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hjpa4bf6/3/)

Comment: If I change it to "pure-input-1" rather than "pure-input-1-2" then it breaks: https://jsfiddle.net/hjpa4bf6/5/

Comment: Because `pure-input-1` has a rule saying `width: 100%`, forcing the input to occupy the entire line. You can override that, as well. https://jsfiddle.net/hjpa4bf6/6/

Comment: hmmm..it still breaks

Comment: In the fiddle demo? Not breaking here... Also, you're working with a library that is applying lots of code to your elements. Go into the inspector (F12 on Chrome) and review the CSS being applied so you can add, remove and adjust styles, as needed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a media query that is applying tules to to the `input` and the `button` from 0px - 480px. If you remove or override these, your fields will behave the same way as > 480px screen widths.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code within your existing code, hope this will help you.

```css
.pure-form fieldset{
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0 45px 0 0;
  margin: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input {
  font-size: 16px;      
  border-radius: 0px;
  height: 30px;
}
.pure-form .pure-input-1-2{
  width: 100%;
}
.pure-button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  align-self: flex-start;
  background: red;
  background-position: 0 0;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pure-g">
  <div class="pure-u-1">
    <form class="pure-form">
      <fieldset>
        <input type="text" class="pure-input-1-2" />
        <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">
          <span></span>
        </button>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that seems to work but why isn't the "padding-right: 50px;" not being respected? https://jsfiddle.net/hjpa4bf6/7/