# CSS inline block white space

Tags: css

I trie doing different [things](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) but can't seem to get rid of the white space between 2 inline-blocks here, thus `list` is not next to `inline-block-div`:

```css
.parent {
  border: 10px solid red;
}

.list {
  border: 5px solid green;
  margin-top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}

.inline-block-div {
  border: 5px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="list">
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="inline-block-div">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste pariatur autem ipsam. Quidem beatae ipsum mollitia unde ab vitae consequatur culpa alias accusantium corporis. Sapiente autem voluptatibus sunt asperiores temporibus.</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use flex. Flex is very useful to develop.

```css
.parent {
  border: 10px solid red;
  display: flex;
}

.list {
  border: 5px solid green;
  margin-top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}

.inline-block-div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="list">
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="inline-block-div">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste pariatur autem ipsam. Quidem beatae ipsum mollitia unde ab vitae consequatur culpa alias accusantium corporis. Sapiente autem voluptatibus sunt asperiores temporibus.</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I know I can do it with flexbox but I want to understand why inline-block isn't working

Comment: I know one way to solve your problem. If you set *{font-size: 0pt}, you can't see white space between inline-block. but I think it's not good way to solve.

Comment: @stackjlei Do you want like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mMmNaE

Comment: thanks @YoungKyunJin

Comment: @stackjlei, 'inline-block' _is_ working, exactly as it was supposed to. It places the elements in the run of text, so whitespace characters between them are treated exactly as white spaces between words in the text. If it's not what you want, you probably don't need inline-block. In the past, web devs had to resort to inline-blocks for layout because there were almost no other option, but currently we have proper tools that don't have to rely on hacks for that.

Answer (score 2):

The space actually comes from HTML. By default space will be added to **inline-block** elements. I hope you knew to fight the space's. And another issue in your **CSS** is you forgot to add **box-sizing:border-box** property.

Without this property width is calculated as follows

width: 75% + border-left-width + border-right-width. So eventually your width is 
75%+10px. Your width will be added more if any padding mentioned. Try this code instead

```css
div{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.parent {
  border: 10px solid red;
  width:100%
}

.list {
  border: 5px solid green;
  margin-top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}

.inline-block-div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 75%;
  margin-left:-4px;
  border:5px solid blue
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="list">
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="inline-block-div">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste pariatur autem ipsam. Quidem beatae ipsum mollitia unde ab vitae consequatur culpa alias accusantium corporis. Sapiente autem voluptatibus sunt asperiores temporibus.</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Yeah I forgot to add box-sizing

Answer (score 0):

You can make the parent a flexbox to have it fixed

```css
.parent {
  border: 10px solid red;
  display: flex;
}

.list {
  border: 5px solid green;
  margin-top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}

.inline-block-div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="list">
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="inline-block-div">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste pariatur autem ipsam. Quidem beatae ipsum mollitia unde ab vitae consequatur culpa alias accusantium corporis. Sapiente autem voluptatibus sunt asperiores temporibus.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know I can do it with flexbox but I want to understand why inline-block isn't working

Comment: Here you find a full explanation with different solutions for your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801095/inline-block-boxes-not-fitting-in-their-container